# ListView not display column and row in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, arrays, multimedia

I have array of byte in C# and I want to represent array component as `listview`.
I wrote this code but not display anything.
What is the error I am having which makes `viewlist` not to show anything?

```
private void loadToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bmp = File.ReadAllBytes(str);

    ListView listView1 = new ListView();
    listView1.View = View.Details;            
    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
    listView1.GridLines = true;

    listView1.Columns.Add("Header Information",20);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Description",20);

    char x = (char)bmp[0];
    char y = (char)bmp[1];
    string st = null;
    st += st + x + y;
    listView1.Items.Add(st, 0);
    listView1.Items.Add("signature", 1);

    num = Convert.ToInt32(bmp[2]);
    str = num.ToString();
    listView1.Items.Add(str, 0);
    listView1.Items.Add(" bytes size of BMP in Bytes", 1);

    num = Convert.ToInt32(bmp[10]);
    str = num.ToString();
    listView1.Items.Add(str, 0);
    listView1.Items.Add(" bytes offset to start of image data", 1);
}
```

Comment: Do you ever add the `ListView1` object to the `Controls` collection?

Comment: Side note: `st += st + x + y;` — this is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this control to your form or panel like below

```
Controls.Add(listView1);
```

or

```
YourPanelName.Controls.Add(listView1);
```

if you have already added listview by designer ( e.g. named as `ListView1`)

then you don't need to create new list view, you can directly add items

```
//ListView listView1 = new ListView();
listView1.View = View.Details;            
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
listView1.GridLines = true
listView1.Columns.Add("Header Information",20);
listView1.Columns.Add("Description",20);
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {"Information", "Description"}));
```

Comment: where add "Controls.Add(listView1);" in form1_load or in  loadToolStripMenuItem_Click  ??

Comment: ok thank you, but can you help me ,the result print in first column only ,i need to display result in two column

Comment: ok Damith, but result not display in second column only in fist column

Comment: @user2922938 have you try to add items like `.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] {"Information", "Description"})`?

Comment: @ Damith plz, i need your help i am beginner in C# form